# Store data in database while checkbox in foreachloop using laravel

Tags: php, ajax, laravel, checkbox, foreach

I want to store checkbox values in database while the checkbox in foreach loop. Other database columns have single value while the checkbox may have multiple.
Class and section have same value but it only save 1 index value.
I tried something like that in my controller.

```
foreach ($request['asn_sub_id'] as $key => $val) 
            {
                if (!empty($val))
                {
                    $ans = new TblAssignSubject();
                    $ans->asn_class_id = $request['asn_class_id'][$key];
                    $ans->asn_sec_id = $request['asn_sec_id'][$key];
                    $ans->asn_sub_id = $val;
                    $ans->asn_user_id = Auth::user()->id;
                    $ans->asn_status = 'Y';
                    $ans->save();
                }
            }
            return response()->json(["status"=>200]);
```

Comment: what is the error/question here ?

Comment: It shows this error but save 1st value of checkbox "Undefined array key 1"

Comment: ```dd($request['asn_sub_id'])``` and check what's in there; also change if to check for key not for value

Comment: okey let me try

Comment: Here it is : array:3 [
  0 => "1"
  1 => "2"
  2 => "3"
]

Comment: ```$request['asn_class_id'][$key];``` my best guess is that your form input element is like this: ```<input  ... name='asn_sub_id' .. /> instead of ans_sub_id[]```

Comment: no its already in array